# Counting number of matching digits between two integers without global variable

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a function that outputs number of matching digits between two integers with recursion.

```
def digit_match(number1, number2):
    n1 = number1 // 10
    n2 = number2 // 10
    d1 = number1 % 10
    d2 = number2 % 10

    if number1 == 0 or number2 == 0:
        return ????

    if number1 >= number2:
        if d1 == d2:
            for i in range(len(str(number2))):
                return digit_match(n1, n2)
        else:
            return digit_match(n1, n2)
    elif number1 < number2:
        if d1 == d2:
            for i in range(len(str(number1))):
                return digit_match(n1, n2)
        else:
            return digit_match(n1, n2)
```

I was trying to get the number of digit differences between the initial number1 or number2 and final n1 or n2 but i cant since number1 and number2 resets to zero in every recursion.

The thing is, i cant use global or anything that is defined outside of the function, and the function should only accept 2 integers which are the numbers whos digits are being checked

123456 and 3456 would output 4. 12345 and 54321 would output 1.. I was trying to get the output by teh difference between initial and final num1 or num2 but i cant do that since num1 and num2 reset every recursion. How can i do this?

Comment: Instead of repeating the same paragraph, could you use the space to explain with examples what it means for two numbers to have matching digits? Is the position of the digit important? How much is this difference for 901011 and 1000991? Also, you have not asked a question.

Comment: 123456 and 3456 would output 4. 12345 and 54321 would output 1. my mistake not including it. I was trying to get the output by teh difference between initial and final num1 or num2 but i cant do that since num1 and num2 reset every recursion. How can i do this?

Comment: @AhmetCemÇalık, See my answer now. I've edited according to your later requirement.

Comment: why not just `lambda n1, n2: sum(i==j for i,j in zip(str(n1), str(n2)))` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your attempt:

- An unconditional `return` in a `for` loop will make the loop exit on its first iteration, so there is never a second iteration. In fact, there should not be any need for an iteration, since you use recursion to visit all the digits.
- Because of the previous point, you don't need to distinguish between `number1 >= number2` and the other case.
- The base case `number1 == 0 or number2 == 0` is not correct. You should also end recursion when one of the two numbers has just one digit. So this should be  `number1 < 10 or number2 < 10`.
- In the base case you should still check whether the two digits are the same. If so you return 1, and otherwise 0
- In the recursive case take the result from the recursive call, and add 1 to it when the current two digits are equal. When not equal, don't add 1.

You can use the fact that in Python a boolean (expression) can be converted to an int.

Here is the proposed code:

```
def digit_match(number1, number2):
    is_same = int(number1 % 10 == number2 % 10)

    if number1 < 10 or number2 < 10:
        return is_same

    return is_same + digit_match(number1 // 10, number2 // 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, I tested it with a little sample code, it seems to be working.

Good luck ;)

```
def digit_match(number1, number2, n_of_recursion=0):
    n1 = number1 // 10
    n2 = number2 // 10
    d1 = number1 % 10
    d2 = number2 % 10

    if number1 == 0 or number2 == 0:
        return n_of_recursion

    if number1 >= number2:
        if d1 == d2:
            for i in range(len(str(number2))):
                return digit_match(n1, n2, n_of_recursion + 1)
        else:
            return digit_match(n1, n2, n_of_recursion)
    elif number1 < number2:
        if d1 == d2:
            for i in range(len(str(number1))):
                return digit_match(n1, n2, n_of_recursion + 1)
        else:
            return digit_match(n1, n2, n_of_recursion)

a = 75034538
b = 15534548

print(f"Number of recursions : {digit_match(a, b)}")
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, no global no defining outside the function and func should only accept number1 and number2. Thanks for your time anyways

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the comments, I came to know that your requirement vary from the initial question you asked. So, I have edited accordingly.

```
def digit_match(number1, number2, l=[]):
    if number1 != 0 or number2 != 0:
        
        d1 = number1 % 10
        
        str1 = str(number1)
        str2 = str(number2)
        
        con2 = len(str2) ==1 and str2 not in str1
        if len(str1) != 0 and len(str2) != 0:
            if str(d1) in str2:
                l.append(d1)
                number1 = number1 // 10
                
                #if the number1 becomes single digit the quotient will become zero. to restrict this
                if number1 != 0:
                    st_number1 = str(d1)
                    index = str2.index(st_number1)
                    str2 = str2[:index]+ str2[index+1:]
                    
                    #If number2 is smaller after appending the last digit, number2 becomes empty string. to restrict this
                    if str2 != '':
                
                        number2 = int(float(str2))
                        digit_match(number1, number2, l)
            else:
                number1 = number1 // 10
                number2 = int(float(str2))

                digit_match(number1, number2, l)
    return len(l)
            
    
    
#case-1
n1 = 345687123
n2 = 345678
r = digit_match(n1, n2)
print(r)
#output: 6

#case-2
n1 = 345678
n2 = 345687123
r = digit_match(n1, n2)
print(r)
#output: 6
```

Answer (score -1):

nvm i found out

```
def digit_match(number1, number2):
    if number1 == 0 or number2 == 0:
        return 0

    d1 = number1 % 10
    d2 = number2 % 10

    if d1 ==  d2:
        current = 1
    else:
        current = 0

    rem = digit_match(number1 // 10, number2 // 10)

    return rem + current
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. It returns 0 for `digit_match(10, 0)`, yet that should be 1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).